# Restore old multibit wallet

Tags: wallet, multibit

I just found an old backup of a bitcoin wallet on a USB stick containing 4 folders:

- key-backup - empty
- rolling-backup - contains a .wallet file stamped with a date from 2014
- wallet-backup - empty
- wallet-unenc-backup contains a .info file and a .wallet file

The info file includes this

> multiBit.info,1
>
> walletVersion,2
>
> property,walletDescription,Your%20wallet%20description
>
> property,walletBackupFile, *path to the .wallet file*

Is it possible to recover this wallet? I've tried downloading multibit, but the new version needs a phrase (which i don't have) and one of the older versions needs a .key file

Comment: I just replied in this thread a similiar question, maybe this helps? https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69188/i-think-i-found-241-bitcoin - seems like the discontinued webpages for multibit still contain valuable info...

Answer (score 1):

I run a service to crack wallet files and, yes, it is possible to recover funds from MultiBit wallet files.

Usually users password-protect their MultiBit wallet files and if this is the case and you have no idea what the password is, then typically the effort brute-force is too high.

Since this is a wide topic with many tools to use, I advice to start looking at https://github.com/gurnec/btcrecover and then google for more details. PM me if you get stuck in the process.

Answer (score 0):

> **Is it possible to recover this wallet?**

It is probably not feasible if you have no clues to the wallet password.

Multibit classic was superceded by Multibit HD which became defunct a few years ago. There is no support or official documentation available. Not that you would necessarily need it.

The Internet Archive has copies of the old Multibit website, for example

https://web.archive.org/web/20150423050359/https://multibit.org/en/help/v0.5/help_lostOrForgottenPassword.html says

> If you have really, truly lost or forgotten your password and you only have encrypted wallets, then it is likely that you have lost access to your bitcoin.