# My private key has compressed public keys; how do I know how much coin I have?

Tags: private-key, private-key-export

I exported my private key to my desktop, then I tried to copy/paste to another wallet, it is multibit, or bitcoin, from mining back in 2013, 2014, 2015. I'm stuck and don't know how much coin I have. I have synced my wallets a few times, it takes a while, but still shows no coin.

I'm not real educated in all this, I'm learning on my own as I go; any detailed guidance on what to do, or any help at all would be really great. Maybe a better way to ask is: how do I export a private key from a multibit wallet, the private key is 52 characters, meaning it contains compressed public keys, should I import to a bitcoin cash wallet? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: this thread: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/69188/i-think-i-found-241-bitcoin/69201?noredirect=1#comment80347_69201 has many info on multibit and bitcoin wallet. Also several links. You may also want to search the forum for similar wording. You probably won't need to try Bitcoin Cash, as it was not alive in these years. It is the second option, as the fork happened in 2017. First try to see, if you can get your keys. Then let us know, what you have done/achieved, or were you need additional help.