# Trying to open an old wallet.dat (from ~2013)

Tags: wallet.dat

I found my old `wallet.dat` file taken from the bitcoin core wallet I used when mining around 2013, nothing serious tho, just fiddling around. Never been too much into the subject, and now I'm totally out of the loop.

Will explain what I did so far:

I downloaded the latest bitcoin core, opened it and after a few seconds closed it properly, replaced the default `wallet.dat` file (with a size of 1416kb) with a copy of my old one (only 88kb) and opened the program again to let it download blockchain, then noticed that as soon as the program opened, the `wallet.dat` (my old one) file size changed to 688kb, waited for the  whole blockchain to download and noticed the balance it's still 0, the send/receive/transactions screens are also blank, as a vanilla wallet.

Maybe my old wallet file is somewhat an old format and get's erased and treated like a new one?

---

I put back the default wallet created by the program and from inside the program opened my old wallet file, a small window with a progress bar appeared saying "opening wallet *filename*", but it keeps loading forever. Also the file size changed again from 88kb to 688kb.

Any clue of what is happening?

I wan't to transfer whatever is there to some online wallet like coinbase.

Comment: If you look at the `debug.log` file, it should indicate whether the wallet was successfully read or not.

Comment: Have a look at https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/59699/opening-an-old-wallet-dat?rq=1 which is very similar.

Comment: And it should go without saying but: make a backup of the original version of the file!

Comment: You could try checking balance from blockchain, just click on receive and copy the address and search in blockchain.com, youll see you'll how much you got there.